# Java: sum of two integers being printed as concatenation of the two

Tags: java

Consider this code:

```
int x = 17;
int y = 013;
System.out.println("x+y = " + x + y);
```

When I run this code I get the output 1711. Can anybody tell me how do I get 1711?

Comment: Wow, seven answers in a minute...

Comment: LOL impressed that so many people still know about Octal :-).  Given that here's a joke... why to programmers confuse Halloween and Christmas?  Because Dec 25 = Oct 31

Comment: @Eric, haha thanks, I'd never heard of that one before!

Comment: Octal constants... I wish the Java language designers took the opportunity to get rid of them (thank you C# designers!), or at least come up with a different notation.

Comment: Autoboxing....nice when Java introduced it, now `int x` automatically is a assigned `Integer.toString(x);`.

Comment: Class names start with an Uppercase letter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `17` is there directly.

`013` is an octal constant equal to `11` in decimal.

```
013 = 1*8 + 3*1 = 8 + 3 = 11
```

When added together after a string, they are concatenated as strings, not added as numbers.

I think what you want is:

```
int x = 17;
int y = 013;
int z = x + y;

System.out.println("x+y = " + z);
```

or

```
System.out.println("x+y = " + (x + y));
```

Which will be a better result.

Comment: +1, Yep, the order of operations is from left to right so if you want to sum x and y you can either do as you've done, or put brackets around them.

Comment: instead of defining new variable, you can just use (x+y)

Answer (score 8):

There are two issues here: octal literal, and order of evaluation.

`int y = 013` is equivalent to `int y = 11`, because 13 in base 8 is 11 in base 10.

For order of evaluation, the `+` operator is evaluated left to right, so `"x+y = " + x+y` is equivalent to `("x+y = " + x)+y`, not `"x+y = " + (x+y)`. Whitespaces are insignificant in Java.

Look at the following diagram (`s.c.` is string concatenation, `a.a.` is arithmetic addition):

```
("x+y = " + x)+y
          |   |
     (1) s.c  |
              |
             s.c. (2)


"x+y = " + (x+y)
         |   |
         |  a.a. (1)
         |
        s.c. (2)
```

In both diagrams, `(1)` happens before `(2)`.

Without the parantheses, the compiler evaluates left-to-right (according to precedence rules).

```
 "x+y = " + x+y
          |  |
         (1) |
             |
            (2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing string concatenation in the final print, since you're adding to a string.  Since `"x+y = "` is a string, when you add x to it, it's giving you `"17"`, making `"x+y = 17"`.

THe 013 is in octal, so treated as a decimal, you get 11.  When you concatenate this, you end up with `"x+y = 17"` + `"11"`, or `1711`

Comment: 11 is concatenated because of the order of operations is from left to right.  Java first looks at "x+y = " + x, which causes x to be promoted to a String and concatenated onto the first String.  The result is then concatenated onto y, which is also promoted to a String during the operation.

Answer (score 2):

```
"x+y = " + x+y
```

equals

```
("x+y = " + x) + y
```

which equals

```
("x+y = " + String.valueOf(x)) + y
```

which equals

```
"x+y = " + String.valueOf(x) + String.valueOf(y)
```

013 is octal = 11 in decimal

Comment: You can't call toString() on an int.

Comment: Perhaps, I'm a bit rusty in Java, too much C#.

Comment: could become Java if you made them `Integer` not `int` :)

Comment: @Peter and @medopal: You get the same effect in Java 5 because the `int` s are autoboxed to `Integer` s.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers prefixed with 0 are [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). 13 Octal is 11 decimal.

The x + y call treats both paramters as strings, so you are combining the string "17" and "11".

Answer (score 0):

013 is ocatal ... convert it to decimal and you will get 11. Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) for an explanation of the octal system.

Answer (score 0):

It's string concatenation of decimal 17 and octal 13 (equivalent to decimal 11).

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be interpreting y as using octal notation (which evaluates to 11). Also, you're concatenating the string representations of x and y in System.out.printLn.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add to Reed's explanation that 013 is interpreted as Octal 13, which is decimal 11.

Answer (score 0):

everyone mentioned `0` makes the number octal.
I just want to add that **`0x`** makes it hexadecimal